Sci-fi show about a young girl that goes into a cyber world
I don't remember a whole lot about this show but I've exhausted Google searches and still cannot find it. I saw it a long time ago before streaming was even a thing.
It was about this girl and her dad. I think her name was Zoe/y but don't quote me on that. Anyway, there was this cyber world, kinda like realistic VR. Their "avatars" were basically just people in a cyber world. I can't really recall much, since it's been so long, but I think the girl dies or goes missing or something but is still in the computer.
I feel I should mention that this is not an anime, nor is it animated. I don't know, it's really bugging me that I can't remember more. I hope someone might know.

In roughly which year did you read this?

It's from 2010 so not that old, but are you thinking of Caprica, the prequel to the reimagined Battlestar Galactica?
Zoe was the daughter of Daniel Greystone who is in the process of designing the Cylons. She dies in the pilot episode but a version of her continued to exist as an avatar in a virtual reality. The VR setting was essentially an alternative real world as I recall, no more fantastic than the sci-fi setting of the overall show.
Amongst the plot threads is one of Daniel trying to bring her back by downloading her to a Cylon body.
Creating an avatar (brief clip):



Series trailer:




That's it! Thank you, it was really bugging me.

"From before streaming was even a thing." Netflix subscribers in 2010: 18 million...

@Mr47, Simply knowing that Netflix had subscribers doesn't tell the whole story. They had more than six million subscribers in 2006, but they didn't start streaming until 2007.

I think OP simply forgot two words: "before streaming was even a thing for me."
